# What happens if I don't use my Indian visa? Is it likely to cause problems in future?

Tags: visas, india, uk-citizens

I am a British citizen. I recently applied for (and was granted) a multiple-entry 6-month Indian business visa. It looks likely now that I will not use it (the trips were cancelled for business reasons), but I wondered - will this have any repercussions on future travel to India or elsewhere? I can provide a reasonable explanation for why I never used it, of course - will that even be needed if I apply to visit India again (as a tourist or for business)?

Comment: I suppose you might be asked, but it must be fairly common for people's travel plans to change; cancellation of a trip for business reasons must be especially common.  That shouldn't keep you from being granted future visas.  My wife was accepted as a landed immigrant in Canada, but never moved there.  She got a raised eyebrow when she later applied for a short-term visa, but nothing more than that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No**, it's fine.  Unused visas are common for business travellers (I have several in my passports), and are not considered a problem for future visa applications, at Immigration, etc.

Answer (score 7):

To elaborate on jpatokal answer:

- Other countries do not care - at all. They often cannot even tell if you used the visa or not. Specially multiple-entry visa do not show on the visa page itself if they have been used or not. You would have to go through the whole passport and check for stamps that would fall into the timeline of the visa validity.
- India does not care, either. Trips get cancelled all the time, specially in business. It's a normal thing. Even if someone at the immigration asks you (they have the right of course to ask you anything), simply stating that you were assigned to a project that was then cancelled is a perfectly fine reason. As always in business: Blame your boss. I would be very surprised however if they ever ask you. Immigration generally only cares when you do come into their country, not when you stay at home.

Answer (score 1):

Its not an issues at all,its normal on business trips.will not affect in future if you are applying again as tourist or for business.you are asked to provide explanation is happened to be very rare situation.